# AWS boto3 create_policy() - specify policyDocument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, iot, boto3, policy

I am using python's boto3 library to interface to AWS IoT. I want to use create a policy using [create_policy() API](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.create_policy) but I do not understand what to use for **policyDocument** field. I think it is related to the [policyStatement](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policies.html), but I can't figure out the syntax. Here's what I have so far.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()

thingType = 'TpmStation'
thingBaseName = thingType + '-'
thingPolicy = thingType + '-Policy-GenDerivedKey'

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

try:
    # Use system hosted credentials - see
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
    client = boto3.client('iot')

    policyDocument = {}
    policyDocument['Statement'] = []
    policyDocument['Statement'].append({})
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Effect'] = 'Allow'
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'] = []
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:Connect')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:Publish')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:Subscribe')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:Receive')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:GetThingShadow')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Action'].append('iot:UpdateThingShadow')
    policyDocument['Statement'][0]['Resource'] = '*'
    response = client.create_policy(
        policyName = thingPolicy,
        policyDocument = policyDocument
    )
    if 200 != response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']:
        eprint(Fore.RED + "ERROR: Unable to 'create_thing_type' " + Style.RESET_ALL)
        sys.exit(1)
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Created new policy '" + thingPolicy + "'" +
            Style.RESET_ALL)

except ClientError as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    eprint(Fore.RED + "ERROR in " + fname + ':' + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + ' - ' + e.response['Error']['Code'] + ' - ' + e.response['Error']['Message'] + Style.RESET_ALL)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many iterations, here's what I found that works

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import re
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()

thingType = 'TpmStation'
thingBaseName = thingType + '-'
thingPolicy = thingType + '-Policy-GenDerivedKey'

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

try:
    # Use system hosted credentials - see
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
    client = boto3.client('iot')

    awsAccount = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
    awsRegion = boto3.session.Session().region_name
    policyDocumentStr = '''
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:Publish"
                    ],
                    "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:%s:%s:topic/Request"]
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:Subscribe"
                    ],
                    "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:%s:%s:topicfilter/Response"]
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:Receive"
                    ],
                    "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:%s:%s:topic/Response"]
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": ["iot:Connect"],
                    "Resource": ["*"]
                }
            ]
        }
    '''%(awsRegion, awsAccount, awsRegion, awsAccount, awsRegion, awsAccount)
    pattern = re.compile(r'[\s\r\n]+')
    policyDocumentStr = re.sub(pattern, '', policyDocumentStr)

    response = client.create_policy(
        policyName = thingPolicy,
        policyDocument = policyDocumentStr
    )
    if 200 != response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']:
        eprint(Fore.RED + "ERROR: Unable to 'create_thing_type' " + Style.RESET_ALL)
        sys.exit(1)
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Created new policy '" + thingPolicy + "'" +
            Style.RESET_ALL)

except ClientError as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    eprint(Fore.RED + "ERROR in " + fname + ':' + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + ' - ' + e.response['Error']['Code'] + ' - ' + e.response['Error']['Message'] + Style.RESET_ALL)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: it probably was different in the previous boto3, but currently no need for the \s\r\n replacement. instead: policy={"key": "value", .....} and then client.create_policy(policyDocument=json.dumps(policy), ....)